# DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID equivalent in Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

What is the equivalent of DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID (SQL Server) in Postgres?

```
 select DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID();
```

As per the SQL Server documentation, DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID is "database principal ID of the current user." And "When principal_name is omitted, DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID returns the ID of the current user."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/database-principal-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I tried finding out it on google, but could find any equivalent to this.

As DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID() returns ID of the current user, I found the following Postgres query. But I am not sure if this query is similar to DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID. The below query returns OID. Please confirm?

```
 select usesysid from pg_user where usename = CURRENT_USER;
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with SQL Server -- is "principal_id" the owner of the database?

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly is this principal_id does or which purpose it serves in SQL Server. What problem are you solving with obtaining that information?

Comment: Quite hard for PostgreSQL dbas to understand what a principal means:-D Is it something tied to the user's current session? Does this help you further: `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = 'postgres';`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am migrating an existing application, which uses this ID(int) to insert another table. Thanks

Comment: @richyen, I think it is not owner of the database, but it is Id of the current user. Thanks.

Comment: @JimJones OK, let me try the query. Thanks